# Soundproofing a wooden door with a mirror

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

To what extent is it viable to glue a large mirror on a solid wood door for sound insulation?

From my point of view, if I will glue a mirror covering most of the door area on a double-sided thick self-adhesive tape, then this will serve as a barrier for sound vibrations.

- The door frame and threshold are already tight enough to the door itself and they have rubber seals.
- car sound proof foam and something like this will not fit because I want to keep both sides of the the door eye pleasant
- I want a mirror on the door not because I really need it, but because I'm fine with it and it can cover sound insulation while not making the door look awful like this one

[image]

Comment: Sound is vibrations, a mirror is solid as is a solid wood door.  You want something soft/spongy to dampen the vibrations, solids transmit the vibrations.  Would not trust tape to hold a large mirror, just asking for seven years bad luck.

Comment: If wanting to mount a mirror for different reasons than sound proofing, could add sound proof foam between the mirror and door.  Mount the mirror using isolation mounts(rubber thingies) rather than tape.

Comment: Does this mirror have a frame? Is it quarter-inch thick or thinner?   Your answers will help with mounting advice. I agree tape is insufficient.

Comment: In general, increasing the mass between the sound source and your ear decreases sound transmission. (Compare a thick door versus a thin door.) Whether you will be able to notice the difference is the question.

Comment: I would be concerned that glue or tape may not work well with the mirror backing/silvering material. And solid glass does not absorb sound.

Comment: I would abandon this idea. It would be cheaper to replace the door than buy a 6ft toughened glass mirror to go over it. Non-toughened, you will be waiting to pick up the pieces first time the door slams. Quick price-up in the UK gives £650 for a 6.5x2.5ft mirror.

Comment: @Tetsujin what a difference in prices we have! In Russia almost a door size (1ft lower) mirror in IKEA will cost around £45. In the same time a decent soundproof door fill cost around £400 + £30-50 to replace it.

Comment: A mirror from Ikea isn't going to be toughened glass - they assume you're not going to stick it to a door & bang it around. Same in the UK, you can get a regular mirror for the same kind of price… but you can get a door for £30 too, so long as you don't want it to be sound-proof.